# How can I associate a dict key to an attribute of an object within a list?

Tags: python, object, dictionary

```
class SpreadsheetRow(object):
def __init__(self,Account1):
    self.Account1=Account1
    self.Account2=0
```

I have a while loop that fills a list of objects ,and another loop that fills a dictionary associating Var1:Account2. But, I need to get that dictionary's value into each object, if the key matches the object's Account1.

So basically, I have:

```
listofSpreadsheetRowObjects=[SpreadsheetRow1, SpreadsheetRow2, SpreadsheetRow3]
dict_var1_to_account2={1234:888, 1991:646, 90802:5443}
```

I've tried this:

```
for k, v in dict_var1_to_account2.iteritems():
    if k in listOfSpreadsheetRowObjects:
        if self.account1=k:
              self.account2=v
```

But, it's not working, and I suspect it's my first "if" statement, because listOfSpreadsheetRowObjects is just a list of those objects. How would I access account1 of each object, so I can match them as needed?

Eventually, I should have three objects with the following information:
SpreadsheetRow
self.Account1=Account1
self.Account2=(v from my dictionary, if account1 matches the key in my dictionary)

Comment: You need to clarify what your variables are, what is `Account1value`? Should it be `Account1` from the argument? And what are `SpreadsheetRow1`, `SpreadsheetRow2` etc? Are they instances of `SpreadsheetRow`, usually names starting with a capital are classes.

Comment: Edited to hopefully make it more clear

Comment: well since it is a dictionary I'd expect `self.Account2 = dict_of_account1_to_account2[self.Account1]` but I don't understand where you are putting that code, why is it checking `if k in listOfSpreadsheetRowObjects:` that would never come true...

Comment: Account2 doesn't equal account1. Account2 needs to equal the value of the account1 key if they match.

Comment: and I think if k in listOfSpreadsheetRowObjects is my problem, I'm trying to find out if k is in the object in the sheet.

Comment: What should happen if `self.Account1` is not in the dictionary? I'd assume `None` in which case you would just use `d.get(k)` instead of `d[k]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generator expression within `any()` to check if any `account1` attribute of those objects is equal with `k`:

```
if any(k == item.account1 for item in listOfSpreadsheetRows):
```

Comment: "if any(k = item.account1 for item in listOfSpreadsheetRows): "  k== item.account1

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function like this:

```
next(i for i in listOfSpreadsheetRows if k == i.account1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dictionary `d` and want to get the value associated to the key `x` then you look up that value like this:

```
v = d[x]
```

So if your dictionary is called `dict_of_account1_to_account2` and the key is `self.Account1` and you want to set that value to `self.Account2` then you would do:

```
self.Account2 = dict_of_account1_to_account2[self.Account1]
```

The whole point of using a dictionary is that you don't have to iterate through the entire thing to look things up.

Otherwise if you are doing this initialization of `.Account2` after creating all the `SpreadsheetRow` objects then using `self` doesn't make sense, you would need to iterate through each `SpreadsheetRow` item and do the assignment for each one, something like this:

```
for row in listofSpreadsheetRowObjects:
    for k, v in dict_of_account1_to_account2.iteritems():
        if row.Account1 == k:
            row.Account2 = v
```

But again, you don't have to iterate over the dictionary to make the assignment, just look up `row.Account1` from the dict:

```
for row in listofSpreadsheetRowObjects:
    row.Account2 = dict_of_account1_to_account2[row.Account1]
```

Comment: for row in listofSpreadsheetRowObjects:
        row.Account2 = dict_of_account1_to_account2[row.Account1] gives me a KeyError....

Comment: Okay, so I think what was confusing was my variable names. I've changed them to hopefully show what it is I'm doing.